# How to get all pages of a Google site with many pages

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have a Google site and I use **Google Apps Script** to get all the pages of the site and export their data to JSON format.

I use the [getAllDescendants](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/site#getalldescendantsoptions) function with a code similar to this:

```
function getAllSitePages(site) {
  var result = [], i = 0;
  while(true) {
    var pages = site.getAllDescendants({start: i});
    if(!pages || pages.length == 0) break;
    result = result.concat(pages);
    i += pages.length;
  };

  return result;
}
```

But this only gets me the first `891` (?!) pages. If my sites has around 1000 pages, is there a way to get all of them with the Sites Service?

Comment: Did it stop because of a timeout?

Comment: Have you ever tried starting at 892? And posibly includeDrafts, includeDeleted?

Comment: How are you calling the getAllSitePages? how do you know it's only returning only fhe firs `891` pages? (add a [mcve])

Comment: @Cooper site.getAllDescendants({ start: 892 }) returns an empty array. adding includeDeleted: true doesn't change that, but adding includeDrafts: true returns another 24 pages, but that doesn't add to the 928 pages I have in the site, according to the list in the Manage Site page.

Comment: @Rubén As I said, I use Google Apps Script to call it from Google cloud. I wrote logs and saw what is returned. I don't want to expose the private site in which I have the problem and it is not easy to build a new site and create 900 dummy pages just for recreation of the problem.

Comment: Actually, I'm mainly interested to know if someone also faced this problem, or if there is some way to get support from Google.

Comment: Regarding getting support from Goole about Google Apps Script see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support

Comment: Regarding getting debugging help, there is no need to post / share private/sensitive information but you should be able to create a [mcve] and guide others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Rubén Thanks, but as I said, in order to reproduce the problem, you would need to have a site with 900 pages, and that's not easy to achieve.

Comment: I found https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763031 but it doesn't seem Google is really handling such cases (it's from 2015, with no response...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216078/discussion-between-splintor-and-ruben).

Answer (score 0):

For now, I was able to bypass the problem by using the `getChildren` function instead (as I currently don't have any page (including root), that has more than 800 direct children):

```
function getAllSitePages(root, result) {
  result = result || []
  var start = 0;
  while (true) {
    var pages = root.getChildren({ start });
    if (!pages || pages.length == 0) break;
    result.push(...pages);
    pages.forEach(page => getAllSitePages(page, result));
    start += pages.length;
  };

  return result;
}
```